# how to use mysql now() function in cakephp for date fields?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, date

I have this code in my cakephp project:

```
$this->data['MyObject']['expire_date'] = 'NOW()';
```

and...

```
$this->MyObject->save($this->data);
```

But this won't save data in database. After googling I found I can use now() like this. But it seems wrong, what is the correct way to use it?

PS: My MySQL field is of type 'DATE'. It works if I use like this:

```
$this->data['MyObject']['expire_date'] = date( 'Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d")+30,   date("Y")));
```

Comment: Have you considered setting a [DEFAULT constraint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html) to set the value to NOW()?

Comment: I updated question. I requirement is something like "DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 30 DAY)". But even "NOW()" doesn't work!

Comment: That's sortof PostgreSQL syntax - look at [DATE_ADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

Comment: "select DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 30 DAY);" will print "2011-06-02" in MySQL too! :)

Answer (score 17):

```
$this->data['MyObject']['expire_date'] = DboSource::expression('NOW()');
```

Comment: It should be called like this:

`$db = $this->MyObject->getDataSource();`

`$this->data['MyObject']['expire_date'] = $db->expression('NOW()'));`

Comment: This will get you **Non-static method DboSource::expression() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context** in **Strict Mode**. Whoever finds this, please use `$db->expression('NOW()')` as suggested in the other answer.

Answer (score 10):

For cakephp  2.x users:

```
$db = $this->MyObject->getDataSource(); 


$this->data['MyObject']['expire_date'] = $db->expression('NOW()');
```

Answer (score 8):

You can shorten that to

```
$this->data['MyObject']['expire_date'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

By default, date() will take the present time, if you do not pass it a second 'timestamp' argument.

This method is preferable to calling `DboSource::expression()` especially when you want to set it in the controller for various reasons, instead of in the model.

Comment: That's fine (and I had some other formatting in that date formatting), but how to use MySQL functions instead?

Comment: Doing that isn't recommended, since your code would be database dependent. If that's not an issue you can try the method described here : http://cakephp.1045679.n5.nabble.com/REgarding-using-Mysql-functions-like-NOW-CURDATE-etc-tp1309285p1309290.html This uses the datasource directly, but *be warned, this does not do automatic escaping so you have to take care of that*. Better to use `date()` :)

Comment: Generally, if you want SQL that performs well -- you *have* to use native functionality.  And this requirement is simple enough to be supported by most databases...

Comment: Okay, I will use PHP formatting. I prefer to leave it for MySQL than formatting in PHP, though. But still, I'd like to know the syntax. :)

Comment: @omgponies yup, true but in this case, with cake you lose out on all the automagic stuff and you have to do them manually. @pman you can actually use that method if you don't need automatic escaping. But you end up making the code even more verbose. Convention over Configuration can sometimes be a pain :)

Comment: This code assumes that PHP and MySQL are using the same timezone. Using `DboSource::expression('NOW()')` is a safer choice.

Answer (score 0):

For CakePHP 3 (in case someone's searching), you'd need to use the SQL functions:

```
$query = $this->Example->query();
$query
    ->insert(['created','id'])
    ->values(array(
        'created' => $query->func()->now(),
        'id' => $id,
    ));
$result = $query->execute();
```

Sources:

- [query-builder.html#using-sql-functions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-sql-functions)

Comment: Also works with CakePHP 5

Answer (score -3):

```
$this->data['MyObject']['expire_date'] = strtotime('now');
```

Comment: 1) CakePHP does not expect Unix timestamps 2) Passing `now` to `strtotime()` is redundant