# MYSQL date Now() in CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-1.2

I have used following for getting mysql date using CakePHP

```
    $db =& ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default');
    $data['end_date'] = $db->expression('NOW()');
```

and

```
$data['end_date'] = DboSource::expression('NOW()');
```

and

```
$db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default');
$data['end_date'] = $db->expression('NOW()');
```

Above all things give me below array whenever I print it.

```
[end_date] => stdClass Object
            (
                [type] => expression
                [value] => NOW()
            )
```

'end_date' has datetime type. I have also change it to timestamp. but not work.

**What I want** :

I want to save Now() ( mysql date ) in my database field 'end_date'.

Comment: Have you actually run the query? I'm not particularly familiar with the `ConnectionManager` but I would imagine `now()` is generated when you execute the query. `$db->execute($sql);`. This also looks a bit complicated for what may be quite simple (`$this->Model->saveField('end_date', date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));` is sufficient?

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864879/how-to-use-mysql-now-function-in-cakephp-for-date-fields

Comment: @Ross I have date function but I want to add mysql date.

Comment: @Len_D : I have already read this one, You can see description of question, I have tried with all this things.

Comment: So what's the actual problem ("_doesn't work_" is not a proper problem description)? The value is perfectly fine, expression objects are how raw SQL snippets can be inserted into the query.

Comment: @ndm : I want to insert mysql date rather than php date in my end_date field.in the my app, I want to use mysql date.

Comment: @ndm: thanks now its done.I checked this by using print_r,thats why it giving me array.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is just to use `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` (if you are using the TIMESTAMP datatype).

```
$data['end_date'] = DboSource::expression(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

Make sure to set the timezone, or you'll end up with a bunch of warnings, as is PHP's style.

Comment: it give me mysql date or php date?I need mysql date.